# Textjoin within a range every 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to join data every 3 columns within a range and summen this in a result cell
Within every 3 columns lays the datasequense like WEIGHT 300 mm and so on.

[image: example result]

I know i have to have the textjoin function yet i don't know how to approach to do this in a range and split the data every 3 columns

Comment: Going by your explaination the data follows a certain pattern. In that case you could use `=BYROW(A1:F2,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" ",,TAKE(a,,3),"-",DROP(a,,3))))`. I'm not sure how your 3rd line fits in since that clearly does not follow the same 'sequence' as you called it.

Comment: De data is always present within every 3 columns, sometimes it can be 2 columns of just nothing. Do you have a working sample of you're code?

Comment: What? Can you be more thorough with how you want to have data presented, if for example the 1st and last cell are populated while rest are empty?

Comment: Hello JvDV you first answer was the correct one, yyour question about the 3th line is that the data is present within those 3 columns. and then the next data will be present in the next 3 columns, the onlyy thing is that some data is not there so the cell will be blank

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per confirmation by OP, one can use:

```
=BYROW(A1:F2,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" ",,TAKE(a,,3),"-",DROP(a,,3))))
```